# No welcome page after openCPU install in fresh Ubuntu 18.04 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, opencpu

I am trying to install `OpenCPU 2.1` on a fresh free tier AWS server. I followed

[https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/?awsf.getting-started-content=use-case-tmt%23websites-apps], and launched a
Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), x86, free tier server, and obtained 
public and private IP's. Then I follow [https://opencpu.github.io/server-manual/opencpu-server.pdf], section 2.2

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I respond to `grub` prompt to keep local version installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opencpu/opencpu-2.1 -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opencpu-server
```

and OK to defaults on pop-up on `mailname` and `smarthost` prompts.

The results all look OK. The last section reads:

```
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
   systemctl restart apache2
Enabling opencpu in apache...
Reloading apparmor...
Restarting apache...
Installation done!
Setting up libxml-twig-perl (1:3.50-1) ...
Setting up libnet-dbus-perl (1.1.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.13) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-5) ...
```

When I then try to point my browser to `http(s)://your.server.com/ocpu` (of course with the the IP replaced by public IP I got from AWS, and using either `http://` or `https://`), then I get a time-out in the browser window after a minute or so.

Checking `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` provides

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
         └─apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-02-28 09:41:19 UTC; 1min 14s ago
Process: 30750 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 30755 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 30771 (apache2)
   Tasks: 6 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─30771 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─30773 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─30774 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─30775 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─30776 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─30777 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Feb 28 09:41:19 ip-zzz-zz-zz-zz systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 28 09:41:19 ip-zzz-zzz-zz-zz systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 28 09:41:19 ip-zzz-zzz-zz-zz systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

which seems OK. Also, trying a restart:

```
sudo a2ensite opencpu
Site opencpu already enabled
```

does not activate the welcome page. Is there something else that needs to be activated or set?

Comment: Did you open the http ports 80/443 on your EC2 firewall? To test if the server works run this command on the server: `curl --insecure http://localhost/ocpu`

Comment: I get `Redirect to http://localhost/ocpu/test` as a response. I didn't open ports manually.

Comment: Either add the `-L` flag to the curl command to follow redirects or try loading the info page directly like this: `curl --insecure http://localhost/ocpu/info`

Comment: ```# OpenCPU: Producing and Reproducing Results
    Cloud Server (version: 2.1.1)

    ## System
    R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: `sudo ufw status` says `Status: inactive`, so I am going to activate

Comment: No this is the amazon ec2 firewall (security group), not the one on the machine! See screenshots below in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to connect to the server locally to test if it running. On the server run:

```
curl --insecure http://localhost/ocpu/info
```

If you get a response with some info about the server, opencpu is running and the issue is likely the amazon security group is blocking HTTP traffic. See the section below on how to enable this.

On the other hand if the curl command above **did not** work (it gave a timeout erorr), there is a problem with the server and you need to check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

## Enable HTTP(S) in the amazon security group (firewall)

If you still not connect from your browser, the issue is likely that your have not opened the http ports in your EC2 firewall (security group). To check this, open the EC2 management console in your browser and lookup the  **security group** is associated with your EC2 instance. Then add inbound rules to this secruity group to allow port 80 and 443 from any host.

First lookup the security group that is associated with your instance:

[image: screenshot1]

And then add an **inbound rule** to allow port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS):

[image: securitygroup]

Comment: OK good luck! Note that EC2 free tier servers are realllly slow.... but fun to get started.